# Count times a regex pattern appears in a list of strings

Tags: python, regex

Say I have a list of schools:

```py
schools = [
    '00A000',
    '01A000',
    '00B000',
    '01B000',
    '00C000',
    '01C000'
]
```

I'm doing some data exploration and the first thing I want to do is count all the schools like `%A%` (have an `A` in the middle).

I assumed I could use something like the command below:

```py
schools.count('\BA')
```

But it looks like the only way I can that using a regex is with `re` module:

```
[re.findall('\BA', x) for x in schools].count(['A'])
```

Is that the easiest way to do it?

Full code:

```py
import re

schools = [
    '00A000',
    '01A000',
    '00B000',
    '01B000',
    '00C000',
    '01C000'
]

# Data exploration. Find count of all district A schools.

# I thought I could use list's built in count and some kind of string regex for it to
# take in:
schools.count('\BA')
# Above example is invalid.

# It looks like I must loop over with regex and then add a count after, right?
[re.findall('\BA', x) for x in schools].count(['A'])

# Repeat for B and C...
```

Comment: What about `len(re.findall('\BA', ','.join(schools)))`?

Comment: Actually you need this instead `len(re.findall('\BA\B', ','.join(schools)))`, since you just want to match `A` in the middle (I'm assuming that `01B0001A` is not a valid match, per the text of your question). Check my answer.

Comment: Those two _match_ the criteria _"%A% (have an A in the middle)"_. Maybe `%A%` wasn't a good choice but the text explains it better for itself.

Comment: Why are you using a non word boundary `\B`? ANd why only at the beginning? `%A%` means an `A` anywhere, at the beginning or at the end or in the middle it is not the same when you use a non word boundary.

Comment: What about strings like `A` or `AA` or `AB` or `BA` or `ABA`?

Answer (score 1):

You could ditch using regular expressions altogether,  if indeed you want to match "xyAuv" but not "Axyuv" or "xyuvA", you could use:

```
len([1 for school in schools if 'A' in school[1:-1]])
```

If any 'A' in the string would do, of course just use `'A' in school`.

A funnier way to write it is:

```
sum('A' in school for school in schools)
```

but it may be confusing and it is a bit slower.

Or:

```
from functools import reduce                                                                                 
from operator import add                                                                                     

reduce(add, ('A' in school for school in schools))
```

Which is funny but a bit faster.

Comment: Nice solution using string slices!

Answer (score 0):

How about joining the list to a string ans get the number of occurrences:

```
import re
print(len(re.findall(r'\BA',','.join(schools))))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I would go with:

```py
len(re.findall('\BA\B', ','.join(schools)))
```

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 19 2019, 22:52:49) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> schools = [
...     '00A000',
...     '01A000',
...     '00B000',
...     '01B000',
...     '00C000',
...     '01C000',
...     'A0D000',
...     '01B00A'
... ]
>>> 
>>> len(re.findall('\BA\B', ','.join(schools)))
2
```